# Sparse matrix in R using library irlba

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have large data in my database. I have to create a matrix has size 600.000x20.000 or like that, but many of cells will be empty. How can I use this R programming language to create my matrix or by using singular value decomposition(SVD) methods? I do not know using in language R and I'll use the sparse matrix in Java programming? I am so confused...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951286/svd-for-sparse-matrix-in-r). You may check [SparseM](http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/~roger/research/sparse/SparseM.pdf) or [spam](http://nldr.library.ucar.edu/repository/assets/osgc/OSGC-000-000-000-495.pdf) packages as well.